# Abstract signal and noise model for a logarithmic image sensor

Tags: signal-processing, modeling, image-sensor

A conventional grayscale image sensor pixel can be modeled as a "light bucket." Photons arrive on the sensor pixel for a fixed exposure time. The light bucket fills up with photo-electrons linearly proportional to the number of incident photons until its full well capacity is reached. The final readout is a Poisson random variable (shot noise) plus some Gaussian perturbations (due to quantization, dark current and readout noise). This model, although abstracted away from the underlying analog pixel electronics, is a quite useful model of signal and noise in a conventional image sensor pixel.

I am trying to build a similar signal and noise model, abstracted away from the pixel's MOSFET microelectronics, for a [logarithmic image sensor](http://www.centeye.com/technology/47-2/) (similar to Section 2 in [this paper](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hasinoff/pubs/hasinoff-hdrnoise-2010.pdf) by Hasinoff et al. or Figure 1b of the [EMVA 1288](https://www.emva.org/wp-content/uploads/EMVA1288-3.0.pdf) standard.)

1. Is there any notion of saturation for a log pixel?
2. How does shot noise come into play in the logarithmic non-linearity?
3. Is there any notion of "exposure time" or "integration time" to average out shot noise in a log pixel?
4. Is there an EMVA standard (or some other standard) for log sensors (and more generally, for sensors non-linear photo-response, such as a quanta image sensor)?

Comment: Aha, an "is it possible" question.....

Comment: By "is it possible" what I really mean "Have you seen anything like it in literature"?

Comment: Take the tour: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour and you'll probably realize that your question is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have edited the question to tighten it up a bit.

Comment: Slide #54 here seems to have a simple formula for the SNR at large flux levels. http://cafe.stanford.edu/~abbas/group/papers_and_pub/isscc02_tutorial.pdf Perhaps there's some intuitive interpretation of saturation in terms of the photodiode's junction capacitance.